# Unable to sort and index the String which is starting with the special characted

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray

I am Sorting the array and adding it to the tableview and adding the index value also. The problem I am facing is unable to add the string which starts with the special characters but it is working fine if the string contains special characte between first and lastplace. Below is the code am using,

```
self.SectionArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:unsortedSections.count];

for (NSMutableArray *unsortedArray in unsortedSections) {
    NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDictionary *country1 = obj1[@"c1"];
        NSDictionary *country2 = obj2[@"c1"];

        return [country1[@"n1"] compare:country2[@"n1"]];

    }];

    [self.SectionArray addObject:sortedArray];
}
```

Comment: Please show me your full coding

Comment: can you post examples of which characters are you facing problems?